# How to change styling for disabled ListView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to make a disabled `ListView` look the same as a non-disabled `ListView`.

I looked it up and found that you have to set the opacity to 1 and have tried a number of approaches, with and without stylesheets, but none seem to work.  I have tried:

```
listView.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1.0;");

.listView:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}

.listView .list-cell {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}

.listView .list-cell:disabled {
    -fx-opacity : 1.0;
}
```

I have also tried setting the background-color to white but this makes the text invisble for some reason, even though no other color does that. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: can you explain a little more what you are trying to attempt? when is this event fired to make it look disabled, have you tried just setting the Opacity? you can just set `listView.setOpacity(1.0);`

Comment: also just to mention, if you wish to use an external CSS you need to make sure it is on the parent node (best to put it on the root node) then you can assign its style through `listView.getStyleClass().add("definedClass");` and in the external CSS set `.definedClass { -fx-opacity: 1.0}` Just in case you wanted to set a universal CSS. On top of this, you cannot call the external CSS if it has been put on the parent node through SceneBuilder, it has to be added to the root pain through `root.getStyleSheets().add("link");`

Comment: @TravFitzy Replacing the item with a String instead of a Label and using the setOpacity method worked. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad I could be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the opacity in the `disabled` pseudo-class (as you mentioned) should be enough:

```
.list-view:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```

just dont forget to add the stylesheet to the `Scene`:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

As an example:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        ListView<String> lw = new ListView<>();
        lw.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("dog", "cat", "whale"));
        lw.setDisable(true);
        root.setCenter(lw);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the CSS selector is contained in the file `application.css` and this file placed in the same directory as the `Application` class file.

**Note:** If you would like to have the selection also to look like the same, you can define the following selectors also:

```
.list-cell:disabled,
.list-cell:disabled,
.list-view:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```